# Does std::string::reserve change the size of an std::string?

Tags: c++, stl, stdstring

Suppose I use `std::string::reserve` to set the capacity of an `std::string` to 20. Will the length of that string change to 20 or remain zero?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reserve` only increases the capacity, but it'll leave the size untouched. If you'll be appending stuff to the string, `reserve` is useful to prevent having to re-copy everything in the string to a new location when it's resized. That is the difference between [std::string::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) and [std::string::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/).